# Installing cartopy on OSGeo4W

Tags: osgeo4w, cartopy

I am trying to install cartopy on OSGeo4W.  Even though all required packages  already downloaded and updated, the installer won't recognize them.  I keep getting the following error:

```
setup.py:168: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail. 
setup.py:224: UserWarning: Unable to determine Proj4 version. Ensure you have 4.8.0 or later installed, or installation may fail.
Proj4 version 0.0.0 is installed, but cartopy requires at least version 4.8.0.
```

I also tried downloading an older version of cartopy and attempted to build it against the installed shapely and GEOS.  I received a long dump of output, including the error:

```
*LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'proj.lib'
error: command "C:\Users\tug28727\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe"' failed with exit status
1181*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems you need a new proj4 version!?

Comment: Sorry, that was rubbish....are your sure the packages you installed are really in the OSGEO4W install directory? I once had problems writing to that directory...

Comment: You don't mention the method of intallation. Please post exact command that lead to the given output, e.g. `pip install cartopy` or `python setup.py`.

Comment: I am using  'pip install cartopy' to install, which gave me the first error above.    The second error came when I downloaded cartopy 0.11.0 (an older version) and tried to run 'python setup.py'.  Also, yes I am sure that OSGEO4W has all the packages for cartopy.